# How to Pass Query String with Page Url in RegisterClientScriptBlock

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a javascript function 'Calc' which i am calling as

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,typeof(Page),"func","Calc()",true)
```

My problem is that, the page includes some parameters in form of Query String.

The code is working fine in case when there is no **query string** in url but as my page request includes query string, the **javascript** function is not calling.

For Example, When the URL in Browser is -

`www.siteurl.com/MyPage.aspx`

In this case, the above given function is executing without any issue, but when my page url is-

`www.siteurl.com/MyPage.aspx?id=1`

The javascript function is not executing in this case.

Please help me to get out of it.

Comment: Include the function `Calc()` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass params to the calc() function using the following syntax:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,typeof(Page),"func","Calc('" & param1 & "','" & param2 & "');",true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.But my problem is lil bit different.I dont want to pass parameters in my javascript function.I want to call my function from .cs page when the page url contains Query String

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is your Calc function positioned in aspx page ?

client side:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Calc() {
        alert('hi');
    }</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
</div>
</form>
```

server side:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 If Page.Request.Url.Query.Count() > 0 Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "func", "Calc()", True)
End If
    End Sub
```